# Sampling from a multi-variate Gaussian distribution restricted to a hypersphere

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, algorithms, sampling, sampling-theory

I consider a Gaussian distribution with density

$$p({\bf x}) \propto \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}({\bf x} - {\boldsymbol\mu})^\top{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\bf x} - {\boldsymbol\mu})\right]$$

where ${\bf x}, {\boldsymbol\mu}\in\mathcal{S}^{K}$ live on a $K$-dimensional hypersphere. Hence, the normalization constant $C({\boldsymbol\mu}, {\boldsymbol\Sigma})$ is given by

$$C({\boldsymbol\mu}, {\boldsymbol\Sigma}) = \int_{\mathcal{S}^{K}} \text{d}{\bf x}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}({\bf x} - {\boldsymbol\mu})^\top{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\bf x} - {\boldsymbol\mu})\right].$$

**Question:** I am trying to find an (efficient) algorithm to sample from this distribution, particularly in high dimensions ($K \approx 500$).

I so far used rejection sampling, but at least a naive version of that doesn't scale to high dimensions. If it helps, $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ can be considered a diagonal matrix. I highly appreciate any hint on how to approach this!

Comment: Is $\boldsymbol\mu$ required to live on this hypersphere?

Comment: Good point, yes! I'll add that to the description.

Comment: What do you mean by "this distribution"?  Why can't you sample from this Gaussian via the standard methods?  Are you trying to sample from it, conditioned on the result being on a hypersphere? If so, what is the hypersphere, exactly?

Comment: @D.W. Yes, the problem is that I want to sample from a slice of the distribution that corresponds to all points lying on the hypersphere. Is that answering your question?